# How to override a css class in style component

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

In `Search.tsx`:

```
import { SearchInput } from Search.styles.ts

<SearchInput
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={values["searchValue"]}
    placeholder="Search"
    type="text"
    name="searchValue"
/>
```

Output html:

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <span class="InputWrapper">
        <input placeholder="Search" name="searchValue" class="Input input normalVariant" formnovalidate="" type="text" value="" >
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In `Search.styles.ts:`

```
import * as Toolkit from "@some_repo/toolkit";
export const SearchInput = styled(Toolkit.Input)`
  InputWrapper: 100%
`
```

I want set `InputWrapper: width 100%`, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just like css.

```
import * as Toolkit from "@some_repo/toolkit";
export const SearchInput = styled(Toolkit.Input)`
  .InputWrapper {
    width: 100%;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as Toolkit from "@some_repo/toolkit";
export const SearchInput = styled(Toolkit.Input)`
  width: 100%;
`
```

Comment: Say InputWrapper is deep inside. How do I style it?

Comment: Could you show me the code or provide codersandbox? I'm not sure what changes for you when it's deep inside

Comment: I have updated the output html. My question is that I want to override the style of InputWrapper. Is Toolkit.Input only representing the most outer element?

Comment: It's representing the inner most element